# MySQL set innodb_buffer_pool_size in my.cnf file - not found

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I need to increase MySql memory for innodb but i cannot find the variable "innodb_buffer_pool_size".
I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed and MySQL 5.7
In stackoverflow, some posts says to modify the my.cnf file and increase the variable "innodb_buffer_pool_size", but I don't find the variable.

In my Ubuntu server, here is my my.cnf file (etc/mysql/my.cnf):

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

This is my /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

```
[mysql]
```

And this is /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld]
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
log-error   = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# By default we only accept connections from localhost
bind-address = *
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
default_password_lifetime = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every config variable is in the file.

Variables that are not present in the file are given a default value that is compiled into the mysqld binary.

In the case of innodb_buffer_pool_size, the default is 134217728 (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size).

To set a non-default value, you must add a line to one of the config files.

You may also want to create a new config file for your local config customizations. You can put the file under either of the `.d` directories named in the `!includedir` directives. If you create a new config file, remember to put the setting under the option heading `[mysqld]`.

Comment: Thank you @Bill Karwin,This is the first time I modify mysql confg files. I need to increase memory until 2GiB. is this correct? "innodb_buffer_pool_size=2097152" into /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.

Comment: That would work. You can also shorten it to `innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G` which is a bit easier. Remember to restart the mysql server daemon after editing the config file. In the case of buffer pool size, in MySQL 5.7 and later you can [change it without restarting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html#innodb-buffer-pool-online-resize).